# Not able to select row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid.Everything is fine,but a small issue.I am not able to select any row other than the first row. When ever I click on any ,row the first row is always getting selected.
   If any one have any idea,please share.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose that you have id duplicates in the input data of jqGrid. You should understand that ids will be used as the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements which represent rows. The ids have to be unique on the whole HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Actually that was the reason :)

Answer (score 3):

you have to put in **one** column in your colModel: **key:true**

```
     colModel: [{ name: 'Código', index: 'Codigo', key: true, width: 50 },
                { name: 'Titulo', index: 'Titulo', width: 245 }]
```

is necessary that the ids, populated are different, for obvious reasons

Comment: If you put "key:true" on a column in your colModel then that value will be inserted into the id attribute of the <tr> tag in the rendered grid.

Comment: This is my cause. Thanks